# Does CSS Positioning Affect SEO

Tags: seo, content

If I positioned the very first content that appears in my code below the fold, would that content be given less weight and therefore be less effective with SEO?

In addition, if I had a large image that took up most of the top of the screen and resulting in my content being below the fold or toward the bottom of the screen, would that content be given less weight?

**Note** This is content that occurs early on in my code. I'm not talking about having a ton of content and if the content that occurs later would be given less weight, but if content that occurs early on put ends up below the fold would be given less weight.

Comment: It can, but not in the case you are describing.

Comment: Please do not ask the same question again after the first one has already been closed. Doing so can result in the system revoking your question-asking privileges.

Comment: These questions are similar, but not related for the following reasons. 1)The one question you marked as supposedly duplicate deals only with display:none, this is with the entirety of CSS. 2)This question asks about the weight of keywords it gives no mention of SEO penalties, while the other question is strictly about penalties and 3)This question is informational, while the other question is regarding how to specifically make an adjustment to my website 4) I wasn't even asking about the same component. This was about where content was located, my other question was about a JavaScript slider.

Answer (score 1):

CSS does not effect SEO. You would need to check your HTML code. That is how search engines see your site and not graphically like humans do. So positioning via CSS has no effect on SEO, however, the position within code can. As well, image size will have no relative effect either.

But do know that Google will check using other browser like methods that will at least check the below the fold issue. This is something to consider. This check is not done often and sites do not generally get penalized for this, but can be if advertising is top heavy. There are plenty of high performance sites where the content appears just below the fold.

Having said that, you are *always* better off having content above the fold. This is a UX (user experience) metric that can reduce bounce rates as well as pages read per user, time per page, and time on site. Giving the user a nibble to read encourages the user. BTW- nibble, image, content works well rather than image, content which is often seen in blogs. The nibble can be beside the image or above. Images, if attractive, can encourage the reader. It is eye candy, but if an image is too large and pushes the content below the fold, this effect may be lost. Also, make sure the image is not too involved and high quality. Make sure the image is topic related and appropriate. There is no sense in confusing or offending the user.

Comment: I tried to use the image to give a minimalist experience which I thought would reduce bounce rates

Comment: @etangins It is always about user experience. Style is a major part of the mystery of how to motivate a user. Each audience is different. I too have used images for effect and style- some of it rather shocking and some of it minimalist like you are. I say go for it! I was just pointing out some traditional uses and where people can get into trouble.

Comment: To clarify, because I know that Google does give less weight to content that comes later on (for example, keywords at the bottom of an article are not weighted as much as those at the top), are you saying that having my content below the fold will not hurt SEO?

Comment: @etangins Not necessarily. I just know that some sites do perform well and the content is below the fold. It may be that they would perform better with content above the fold. I can say from my experience, I do not like scrolling to see content, however, for some sites where the content is known to be quality, I am a bit more patient. In the end, limiting the banner/header portion of a sites page to allow content to at least begin to appear above the fold could translate to better performance- lower bounce rate, more pages read, more time on site. It is about user experience. Google be damned.